# scheme - quotation and auxiliary syntax

Tags: scheme, racket

For some reason the following macro will fail to work with quotation.

```
(define-syntax expand
    (lambda (stx)
      (syntax-case stx (break)
        [(_ k () (ys ...)) (begin (println (syntax->datum #'(ys ...))) #'(ys ...))]
        [(_ k ((break) xs ...) (ys ...)) #'(expand k (xs ...) (ys ... (k (void))))]
        [(_ k ((es ...) xs ...) (ys ...)) #'(expand k (xs ...) (ys ... (expand k (es ...) ())))]
        [(_ k (a xs ...) (ys ...)) #'(expand k (xs ...) (ys ... a))])))

(define-syntax loop
    (syntax-rules ()
      [(_ e es ...)
       (call/cc (lambda (k)
                  (let l ()
                    (expand k (begin e es ...) ())
                    (l))))]))

(loop (list 1 (break)))
;; => works fine 

(loop (quasiquote (1 (unquote (break)))))
;; => break: unbound identifier in module in: break
```

I am kind of surprised to see why the second case fails.

And the following debug information is printed for both cases.

```
;; case 1
'(begin (expand k (list 1 (break)) ()))
'(list 1 (k (void)))

;; case 2
'(begin (expand k `(1 ,(break)) ()))
'`(expand k (1 ,(break)) ())
```

Please note that in the output for case 2 after the `quasiquote` expansion, the rest `(1 ,(break))` is somehow not expanded.

Not sure why this will happen.

Thanks

Comment: *the output for case 2 after the `quasiquote` expansion* I can not see it in your question. Last line ``'`(expand k (1 ,(break)) ())`` represent state **before** `quasiquote` expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the macro expander doesn't expand macro calls that appear under a `quote` or `quasiquote`. For example:

```
(define-syntax-rule (pipe) "|")

> (quote (pipe))
'(pipe)                ; not "|"
> (quasiquote (pipe))
'(pipe)                ; not "|"
```

This can be solved by doing recursion on the syntax object directly at compile time, instead of doing recursion by returning a syntax object with a macro call inside of it.

In general, translate code like this:

```
(define-syntax expand
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx literals
      cases
      [pattern #'(.... (expand stuff) ...)]
      cases)))
```

Into code like this:

```
(begin-for-syntax
  (define (expand stx)
    (syntax-case stx literals
      cases
      [pattern #`(.... #,(expand stuff) ...)]
      cases)))
```

In your particular case, you probably want `expand` to be a 3-argument function, which runs and recurs completely at compile time.

```
(begin-for-syntax
  (define (expand k xs ys)
    (with-syntax ([(ys ...) ys])
      (syntax-case xs (break)
        [()                (begin (println (syntax->datum #'(ys ...))) #'(ys ...))]
        [((break) xs ...)  (expand k #'(xs ...) #'(ys ... (k (void))))]
        [((es ...) xs ...) (expand k #'(xs ...) #`(ys ... #,(expand k #'(es ...) #'())))]
        [(a xs ...)        (expand k #'(xs ...) #'(ys ... a))]))))
```

Then you can call this compile-time function in the implementation of the `loop` macro:

```
(define-syntax loop
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_ e es ...)
       #`(call/cc (lambda (k)
                    (let l ()
                      #,(expand #'k #'(begin e es ...) #'())
                      (l))))])))
```

#### However, this isn't the best way to do a looping macro.

I'm hoping the compile-time function above helps you understand what's possible with macros. However, for the `loop` macro it shouldn't be needed. A *syntax-parameter* provides a much easier way to do this.

```
(define-syntax-parameter break
  (lambda (stx) (raise-syntax-error #f "cannot be used outside of loop" stx)))

(define-syntax loop
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ e es ...)
     (call/cc (lambda (k)
                (define (break-function) (k (void)))
                (syntax-parameterize ([break (make-rename-transformer #'break-function)])
                  (let l ()
                    (begin e es ...)
                    (l)))))]))
```

In fact, a `loop` macro like this is one of the examples used in the paper [*Keeping it Clean with Syntax Parameters* section 4](http://www.schemeworkshop.org/2011/papers/Barzilay2011.pdf#page6), called `forever`, where it calls the breaking syntax parameter `abort`.